# wp_script_add_data doesn't seem to work

Tags: theme-development

I have tried following the [codex](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_script_add_data/) following various threads here, simple, copy-paste various examples but to no avail. It just doesn't work.

Has it been depreciated? Has anyone got this to work in any recent version of WP or 5.7 specifically

```
 function my_scripts() {
wp_enqueue_script( 'bs-popper', 'https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@popperjs/core@2.9.1/dist/umd/popper.min.js', array('jquery'), _S_VERSION, true );
wp_script_add_data('bs-popper' , array('integrity') , array('sha384-XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX')); 
} 
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'my_scripts' );
```

[EDIT] Simple:
Above example was from a version that had more than one but this simple one doesn't work either

```
wp_script_add_data('bs-popper' , 'integrity' , 'sha384-XXXXXXX');
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not what `wp_script_add_data()` does.

It doesn't support adding arbitrary attributes to the script tag. It lets you add metadata to the enqueued script, but out of the box the only key that WordPress supports is `'conditional'`, which is used for telling the script whether to load in certain versions of IE. For example, this:

```
wp_script_add_data('bs-popper' , 'conditional' , 'IE 9');
```

Will result in this:

```
<!--[if IE 9]>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@popperjs/core@2.9.1/dist/umd/popper.min.js" id="bs-popper-js">
<![endif]-->
```

But this:

```
wp_script_add_data('bs-popper' , 'attribute' , 'value');
```

Won't do anything.

If you want to be able to add attributes to scripts that way, you need to use the `script_loader_tag` filter to filter the HTML of the `<script>` tag to add the attribute if the data has been added with `wp_script_add_data()`. There's an example of that [here](https://gist.github.com/wpscholar/7b343ec2a8c52752dbc0), but for your use case it would look like this:

```
add_filter(
    'script_loader_tag', 
    function( $tag, $handle ) {
        $integrity = wp_scripts()->get_data( $handle, 'integrity' );

        if ( $integrity ) {
            $tag = str_replace( '></', ' integrity="'. esc_attr( $integrity ) .'"></', $tag );
        }

        return $tag;
    }, 
    10, 
    2
);
```

Comment: That worked Thanks: For multiple I just added another one in the same function, it worked but is that the way to go?

Answer (score 2):

Introduced in WP 5.7.0 (a few months before this post), [the `wp_script_attributes` filter](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/wp_script_attributes/) can be used to add arbitrary attributes.

Example:

```php
add_filter( 'wp_script_attributes', static function ( array $attr ) : array {
    if ( 'bs-popper-js' !== $attr['id'] ) {
        return $attr;
    }

    $attr['integrity'] = 'sha384-XXXXXXX';

    return $attr;
} );
```